# Automatically create email link from a static text

Tags: php, email, url, hyperlink

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically link the email addresses contained in a simple text from the db when it's printed in the page, using php.

Example, now I have:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor email@foo.com sit amet
```

And I would like to convert it (on the fly) to:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="mailto:email@foo.com">email@foo.com</a> sit amet
```

Comment: Your *before conversion* is exactly the same as your *after conversion*. Please, explain a little more what you need.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will need to use regex:

```
<?php

function emailize($text)
{
    $regex = '/(\S+@\S+\.\S+)/';
    $replace = '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>';

    return preg_replace($regex, $replace, $text);
}


echo emailize ("bla bla bla e@mail.com bla bla bla");

?>
```

Using the above function on sample text below:

```
blalajdudjd user@example.com djjdjd
```

will be turned into the following:

```
blalalbla <a href="mailto:user@example.com">user@example.com</a> djjdjd
```

Comment: thanks, I tried but it seem to not work. I've passed the text via "$text" and put an "echo $result;" after the } but nothing come out. Maybe I'm doing a stupid error, I'm just started to learn php.

Comment: Yup, I tested it and didn't worked at first. I just retested it. Now it works like a charm. If youw ant to see the ouput of the regex just comment out the preg_replace / return part. Otherwise the preg_match/var_dump wont be displayed ;-)

Comment: Not quite working right, my email link is coming out like this:

<a href="mailto:test@email.com</div></div></div>" >test@email.com</a>

Comment: Excellent - works well. How you would prevent it being encoded again if the code is reapplied to the output string. In my case I would like to run this code over some HTML before saving it in the database, but the code that has been fetched from the database may already have mailto: linked email addresses. I end up with:

`Bob Brown <a <a href="mailto:href="mailto:bob@turboweb.co.nz">bob@turboweb.co.nz</a>">href="mailto:bob@turboweb.co.nz">bob@turboweb.co.nz</a></a>`

Comment: It doesn't work with `email@email.com.` This regex works better: `'/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]*@\S+\.\w+)/'`

Comment: This works if there is space just after e-mail address. But doesn't work in this situation: email@address.com<br>Test... @NotthingCtrl 's answer is better.

Answer (score 16):

Try this version:

```
function automail($str){

    //Detect and create email
    $mail_pattern = "/([A-z0-9_-]+\@[A-z0-9_-]+\.)([A-z0-9\_\-\.]{1,}[A-z])/";

    $str = preg_replace($mail_pattern, '<a href="mailto:$1$2">$1$2</a>', $str);

    return $str;
}
```

---

Update 31/10/2015: Fix for email address like `abc.def@xyz.com`

```
function detectEmail($str)
{
    //Detect and create email
    $mail_pattern = "/([A-z0-9\._-]+\@[A-z0-9_-]+\.)([A-z0-9\_\-\.]{1,}[A-z])/";
    $str = preg_replace($mail_pattern, '<a href="mailto:$1$2">$1$2</a>', $str);

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: This should be up voted instead of the answer marked as correct, this works much better.

Comment: Does not work for email addresses ala john.does@example.com

Comment: @NotthingCtrl , does this ignore emails that are already linked?

Comment: @OguguaBelonwu nope, it will match them as well. Will fall for `http://example.com/email/hello@example.com/` as well, needs couple tweaks.

Comment: can confirm this works better --- the accepted answer works but it includes stuff like punctuation, etc, if it comes right after the email. So for example: "Send an email to myemail@email.com, or call" produces a match as `myemail@email.com,`. this solves that issue

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I combined (from answers on here) for a function to do this for emails and URLs:

The benefit of this is it does not convert to a link if one is already there.

```
function replace_links( $content ){
    $content = preg_replace('"<a[^>]+>.+?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(?:https?)://\S+"', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('"<a[^>]+>.+?</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(\S+@\S+\.\S+)\S+"', '<a href="mailto:$0">$0</a>', $content);
    return $content;
}
```

Demo:
https://glot.io/snippets/g6nwd6amyo

I also suggest looking at how WordPress handles this, as you know it's battle tested and deals with random issues like periods or other characters after the actual email:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2997-L3055

Look at `make_clickable` and specifically `_make_email_clickable_cb` callback line (this is personally what i ended up using instead due to other regex issues)

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you want...

```
  //store db value into local variable
    $email = "foo@bar.com";
    echo "<a href='mailto:$email'>Email Me!</a>";
```

Comment: no, he probably needs regex to find and replace any emails in the text.

Comment: exactly, convert the email address contained in the text to a "mailto" link with the surrounding text intact